# How to create font face from link and apply as font family dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-face

So I'm loading fonts and then the challenge is that I don't have a @font-face and font-family class as both those things are unknown to me.

I'm getting all the font-families from a user. How can I change that dynamically without knowing anything about the font?